# How to trigger a pipe programmatically in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-pipe

Is there any way to trigger pipe programmatically in Ionic? I have used a pipe to show or hide button by like this:

```html
<ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let item of mylist">
  <ion-card class="card">
    <ion-card-header>
      {{item.name}}
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content no-lines text-wrap>
      <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="ButtonClick1(item.id)" [class.hide]="item.startDate | checkinButtonEnablePipe: item.endDate">Test Button</button> 
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

And the code for my custom pipe is:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import moment from "moment";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
/**
 * Generated class for the CheckinButtonEnablePipe pipe.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe for more info on Angular Pipes.
 */
@Pipe({
  name: "checkinButtonEnablePipe"
})
export class CheckinButtonEnablePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Date, value2: Date) {
    var dtstart = moment(value).format("YYYY/MM/DD, h:mm:ss a");
    var dtend = moment(value2).format("YYYY/MM/DD, h:mm:ss a");
    var dtnow = moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD, h:mm:ss a");
       if (dtnow >= dtstart && dtnow <= dtend)
        return false;
      else
        return true; 
  }
}
```

And I'm checking time by 5 minutes interval and want to show a button if time is between startdate and enddate.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your mean pipe call again by ts file

Comment: yes exactly.I'm getting data from a json webservice ,and after that I dont want to call web service again.I want to control button's visibility by 5 minutes interval ,like the pipe doing in code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution.

```
import {CheckinButtonEnablePipe} from './pipe_path'

constructor(private checkinButtonEnablePipe:CheckinButtonEnablePipe){
    checkinButtonEnablePipe.transform(value1,value2)
}
```